# Pythontex in TeXShop for MAC

Tags: errors, mac, texshop, pythontex, macos

I am trying to use Pythontex in TeXShop but my engine is not working, here is my pythontex engine

```
#!/bin/zsh

# For anaconda distribution of Python, use
#PATH=~/anaconda/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/texbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/Users/enzob/anaconda3/bin
#PATH=/Users/enzob/anaconda3
#PATH=/usr/local/bin

# For system distribution of Python, use
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/texbin:/Library/TeX/texbin

filename=$1

pdflatex --file-line-error --synctex=1 $1

/usr/local/texlive/2023/textmf-dist/scripts/pythontex/pythontex3.py $1

pdflatex --file-line-error --synctex=1 $1
```

every PATH you can see there don't work.
I'am testing my engine with this latex document named `1-A.tex` :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgf,interval}


\usepackage{pythontex}



%%Ensemble des programmes python
%\input{/Users/jlebovits/Dropbox/5-Latex_et_tous_logiciels_de_math_et_terminal/1-Latex/2-Fichiers_Tex_a_inclure/Inputgene/Prog_Python.tex}






\begin{document}


\begin{pycode}
from sympy import *
x, y = symbols('x y')
\end{pycode}

\section{Développements, factorisations...}
Une expression : $x(x + 2y)$
\begin{pycode}
exp = x*(x + 2*y)
dev_exp = expand(exp)
print('diff is diff')
\end{pycode}


La dérivée de la fonction définie par $\cos(x)$ est : $\py{latex(diff(cos(x), x))}$

Le développement de $x(x + 2y)$ est $\py{latex(dev_exp)}$



\begin{sympycode}
A = Matrix([[1, 2], [3, 7]])
\end{sympycode}
%
\begin{equation}
 A 
 =
\sympy{A}
\end{equation}
%
%
\begin{equation*}
 A^2 
 =
\sympy{A**2}
\end{equation*}

eofieofijoij

\end{document}
```

Here is some errors I have: for `PATH=/usr/local/bin`  i have the error`/Users/enzob/Library/TeXShop/Engines/pythontex.engine:13: command not found: pdflatex`

for `PATH=~/anaconda/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/texbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/Users/enzob/anaconda3/bin`  i have

```
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./1-A.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01>
L3 programming layer <2023-06-16>
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-french/french.ldf))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/locale/fr/babel-french.te
x) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/carlisle/scalefnt.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathtools/mathtools.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathtools/mhsetup.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))) (./1-A.tex

./1-A.tex:1: LaTeX Error: Two \documentclass or \documentstyle commands.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.1 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{
                                 article}
```

These are the two errors I have.

If I understand, the `PATH` is where my python exe are ? I have located them in `/usr/local/bin`.

I also have anaconda3 in `/Users/enzob/opt/anaconda3`.

`/usr/local/texlive/2023/textmf-dist/scripts/pythontex/pythontex3.py` is where pythontex3.py is located.

My document `1-A.tex` work because I have what I want when I manually compile it from my terminal window with the command :

```
pdflatex 1-A.tex
pythontex 1-A
pdflatex 1-A.tex
```

Any help or advice?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You say `\input{1-A.tex}`. How does `1-A.tex` look like? The error says "Two \documentclass or \documentstyle commands.", so maybe this file starts with `\documentclass`?

Comment: @JasperHabicht the ```1-A.tex``` document is the one in my post. As you can see it is starting with the ```\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}```. I'am also sure that ```1-A.tex```is working because it's working when I compile it manually in my terminal window with : ```pdflatex 1-A.tex            pythontex 1-A             pdflatex 1-A.tex```

Comment: But why do you put `\input{1-A.tex}` in your code then? If you `\input` a document in intself, this would eventually lead to an infinity loop. I think, you should delete `\input{1-A.tex}` and try again.

Comment: @JasperHabicht I don't know why there is this ```\input```. I have remove it but I still can't compile it via the engine. I think the error is in my pythontex engine, I would like to know what is ```PATH```, maybe it's because I didn't define the right path. Thank you so far!

Comment: Well, the error you showed is most likely related to this `\input`. It seems that Python starts (La)TeX successfully, but then something goes wrong with your (La)TeX code. After removing `\input`, do you still get the same error?

Comment: @JasperHabicht So from TeXShop I am compiling with the pythontex.engine you can see in my original post. When I use ```PATH=~/anaconda/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/texbin:/Library/TeX/texbin``` I have no calling to **pythontex** so my .tex document is compiling right but in the .pdf document there is **??** where the result of my python code should be. When I use ```PATH=/Users/enzob/anaconda3/bin``` I have the error : ```/Users/enzob/Library/TeXShop/Engines/pythontex.engine:22: command not found: pdflatex```.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146810/discussion-between-enzo-ben-and-jasper-habicht).